# Llama index core embbedings

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, llama-index

```py
from llama_index.core.embeddings import resolve_embed_model
```

error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'resolve_embed_model' from
 'llama_index.core.embeddings' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/core/embeddings/__init__.py)
```

After installing the Llama index , I am getting the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the import:

```
from llama_index.core.embeddings import resolve_embed_model
```

with this import:

```
from llama_index.core.embeddings.utils import resolve_embed_model
```

They seem to be moving things around, and the tutorial is not well synchronised with the latest release.